# blob is not a valid utf-8 string error

Tags: apex, callout

```
String body = '' + documentList[0].VersionData+ '';
system.debug('body---'+body);
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBody(body);
req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);       
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint(uploadEndPointURL);
Http ht = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = ht.send(req);
```

How can I upload png file. Tried above code but getting error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use [setBodyAsBlob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_System_HttpRequest_setBodyAsBlob) method instead of `setBody`

> Sets the contents of the body for this request using a Blob.

`VersionData` is already a blob type value.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBodyAsBlob(documentList[0].VersionData);
req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);       
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint(uploadEndPointURL);
Http ht = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = ht.send(req);
```

Verify documentation of the endpoint API how exactly a file should be sent.

Comment: Yes, except... this is multipart form. Additional work is necessary to make this work.

Comment: @Oleksandr Berehovskyi @ 
sfdcfox, Thanks for answering. After using 'setBodyAsBlob' I am getting 'API upload did not contain a file part' error. Basically I wanted to know is there any way by which I can upload any file type like .csv, .png, .txt etc. Thanks

Comment: @user106835 I linked a Q&A that demonstrates how to deal with multipart/form-data. Please read that Q&A again.